# .Net core 6 authorization with bearer token

Tags: .net, .net-core, authorization

I cannot get authorization work with openidconnect. I want to send a token as a header.

My code in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
    {
        o.ClientId = "id";
        o.ClientSecret = "secret";
        o.Authority = "https://something.onelogin.com/oidc/2";
        o.ResponseType = "code";
        o.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
    }
);
```

In addition to this I have app.AddAuthentication() etc.

However, when sending a token as a header: "Authorization":"Bearer ey...", I cannot access the endpoints.

Comment: What error message you get, please mention that as well in the question.

Comment: I am using it together with GraphQL, so the error message is just "not authenticated"...